# How do I get my contact form to work with PHP

Tags: php, html, email, contact-form

I'm sitting on my final project for university right now and am having trouble with the contact form. I have a server to upload and I already tried it to send the mail, however it does not work. I also don't get any error displayed. I`enter code here` would like to know where exactly I need to define my email address and what code needs to be changed to get it to work. I already looked up and tried many possibilities but it doesn't matter where I define my email, it doesn't get sent. Thanks in advance!

```html
<form class="zform">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="to" value="user@domain.extension" />
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Your name" required="required" /> </div>
                                    <div class="col-12 mt-4">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" /> </div>
                                    <div class="col-12 mt-4">
                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Enter your descriptions here…" required="required"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-12 mt-4">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-auto">
                                                <button class="btn btn-md-lg btn btn-outline-primary" type="Submit">
                                                    <span>Send</span>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col">
                                                <div class="zform-feedback"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

```
<?php

    $error = '';

    if ( array_key_exists('to', $_POST) ){
       
        $to         = $_POST['to'];     
        unset($_POST['to']);

        $from       = "user@domain.com";
        $name       = "Website User";
        $subject    = "New Email from My Website";


        if(isset($_POST['from'])){ 
            $from   = $_POST['from'];   
            unset($_POST['from']); 
        }

        if(isset($_POST['name'])){ 
            $name   = $_POST['name'];   
            unset($_POST['name']); 
        }

        if(isset($_POST['subject'])){ 
            $subject    = $_POST['subject'];    
            unset($_POST['subject']); 
        }


        $message = "";
        foreach ($_POST as $field => $data){

            $message = "<html><head><title>$subject</title></head><body>\n";
            foreach($_POST as $field => $data){             
                $message .= "<div style='border-bottom:1px solid #dadada; padding-bottom:15px;margin-bottom:15px;'><strong>".ucwords($field)."</strong><br/>".stripslashes($data)."</div>\n";
            }
            $message .= "</body></html>";

        }


        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
        define('HEADER_TRAIL', "\r\n");
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . HEADER_TRAIL;
        $headers .= ( ! 'EMAIL_HTML') ? 'Content-type: text;' . HEADER_TRAIL : 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . HEADER_TRAIL ;

        // Additional headers
        $headers .= "From: ".$name." <".$from.">" . HEADER_TRAIL;


        if(!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            $error = 
            '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                Error sending message. Please try again.
            </div>';
        }



    } else {
        $error = 
        '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            There is no <strong> "to" </strong> field found in the form. Please follow the documentation.
        </div>';
    }


    if(!empty($error) ){
        echo $error;
    }
    else{
        echo 
        '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            Your message has been sent successfully.
        </div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your form doesn't have a [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method) attribute, so it's using `GET`, not `POST`

Comment: Also, only one of your input elements has a `name` attribute

Comment: Unrelated: one `foreach ($_POST as $field => $data)` should be enough.